# initWithContentsOfFile Deprecated

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, webview

I was wondering what code I could use instead of initWithContentsOfFile: as I've been searching for something that isn't deprecated but cannot find anything. I'm trying to display a local HTML file within a webview, below is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *htmlPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"];
    NSURL *bundleUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]];
    NSString *html = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:htmlPath];
    [self.myWebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:bundleUrl];

}
```

And I'm getting a warning saying that initWithContentsOfFile: is deprecated and would like to know how to update it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"/path/to/file.txt" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

Comment: is it possible to reference a file in the project this way? I ask because I'm thinking of loading a help document to be displayed to the user this way. If so, how do I construct the path? If there's a better way, let me know.

Comment: @VictorEngel Have a look at `NSBunlde`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the newer initializer:

NSString's [`[initWithContentsOfFile: encoding: error:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/initWithContentsOfFile%3aencoding%3aerror%3a) method, where you can get a useful error passed back to you if there are any problems.  I've linked the documentation for you.  If you don't know the encoding of the file, you can also use another method that has a `usedEncoding` parameter.